# Group by in node.js-mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, monk

I want to use group by in my server.js, but i get this error:

```
TypeError:Object #(Collection) has no method 'group'
```

I looked online and saw thats the function's name.

Here is what i wrote:

```
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/Messages');
var collection = db.get('col');
collection.group(['a'], {}, {}, {}, function (e, docs) {
  res.json(docs);
});
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you please provide some more details. Like what is `collection` variable and all ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monk does not implement a [`.group()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/collection.html#group) method on it's own, but there is a `.col` accessor available from which you can get the native [Collection](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/collection.html) object from the underlying driver and use it's methods.

Your usage for [`.group()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/collection.html#group) is a bit off, so I'll use my data an example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5479c4793815a1f417f537a0"),
    "status" : "canceled",
    "date" : ISODate("2014-11-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "offset" : 30,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5479c4793815a1f417d557a0"),
    "status" : "done",
    "date" : ISODate("2014-10-20T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "offset" : 30,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5479c4793815a1f417f117a0"),
    "status" : "done",
    "date" : ISODate("2014-12-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "offset" : 30,
}
```

Then you can just code up a `.group()` statement like this:

```
  var db = require('monk')('localhost/test'),
      sample = db.get('sample');

  sample.col.group(
    ["status"],
    {},
    { "count": 0 },
    "function (obj,prev) { prev.count++; }",
    function(err,docs) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log( docs );
    }
  );
```

But that also goes to show that 99% of the time you probably really want the [`.aggregate()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/collection.html#aggregate) method instead:

```
  var db = require('monk')('localhost/test'),
      sample = db.get('sample');

  sample.col.aggregate(
      [
          { "$group": {
              "_id": "$sample",
              "count": { "$sum": 1 }
          }}
      ],
      function(err,docs) {
         if (err) console.log(err);
         console.log( docs );
      }
  );
```

The aggregation framework is generally a lot more flexible than `.group()` and runs native code operators as opposed to interpreted JavaScript, so it's pretty worthwhile learning.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message says, it appears the `Collection` object does not have `group()` as a method. [Here is the source of what you're dealing with](https://github.com/Automattic/monk/blob/master/lib/collection.js)

And it looks like [someone else has had an issue with this in the past.](https://github.com/Automattic/monk/pull/64)

I don't know too much of using monk (sorry), but it looks like it is very promise driven, so copy-pasting   RomanGorbatko's solution might be what you need.

Comment: Not to sure if you are personally interested or were just posting the links that you found as an answer. But you can call `.group()` or any native collection method using monk. Just use the `.col` accessor.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks for picking this up with a correct answer :)